# Navigation Controller 'Back' button crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2

I started by pushing 2 UIViewControllers in my app delegate homeView and loginView (back button is hidden).

In my loginView I have a condition to check whether to pop to homeView or remain at loginView.

In my homeView I pushed another UIViewController called myMatches and this time I didn't hide the back button.

The crash happens when I press this back button (it will display my homeView for a while and then crashes).

Anyone had encountered this problem before? How did you solve it?

Comment: Edit your question and paste in the crash stack trace and any console messages.  Run under Instruments with the Zombies template.

Comment: Did you check the console? It happens when you release something and refer same when u come back to HomeViewcontroller

Comment: thanks, i think i need to learn to use those instruments first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check in your myMatches dealloc, something(variable,object whatever)release in there.

Comment: thanks I had the habit of releasing everything in the dealloc. so when should i release these variables instead?

Comment: just check if(veriable != nil) then just nil your variable. but if you allocate it or retain it, it's require to release it rather then nil.

Comment: sorry I don't get what you mean, so i have this allocated object property in homeView and MyMatches called currentKey. in MyMatches dealloc i removed the currentKey release and the crash disappeared, thanks to u. so my question is, when should I release currentKey?

Comment: in your dealloc just put if condition before release it 'if(variable != nil)' then release/nil it. so if your variable already nil at that time it will be not release/nil it.